# Mathematical properties of two dimensional projection of three dimensional rotated object

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, recreational-mathematics, analytic-geometry

Please be gentle as I do not have any degree in maths.

By using a compass/straighedge method to construct Metatron's cube, a regular dodecahedron can be inferred from intersecting points. I'm looking for the ratio between the *lengths of the edges* (`blue`) of the dodecahedron and the *radius of the initial circle* (`red`) used for the construction.

What I actually want is to have on of the faces of the dodecahedron, to be a regular pentagon (`purple`) on the two dimensional plane on which it's being projected. If you take a horizontal line through the center of the dodecahedron and rotate the object over that line (`green`).

**1. How many degrees does it need to be rotated to make the irregular pentagon below, regular?**

[image: Example of construction]

**2. Is it true that after this rotation, the circle is *perfectly inscribed* inside the pentagon?**

> **EDIT: please understand that the purple pentagon only appears after a rotation of the resulting dodecahedron in 3D space** [image: dodecahedron rotation]

[image: Circle inscribed in pentagon]

3. Can I then say that if $r = 1$ then $x = 1.45308505601$ by using the formula for calculating the apothem ($DB$) given the length of a side which is: $$y = \frac{s}{2tan\frac{180}{5}} $$

For $y=1$ that gives $1.45308505601$.

(ref: http://www.mathopenref.com/apothem.html)

Comment: can you explain, starting from the initial red circle, how you constructed this? i don't have coxeter's  regulay polyhedra handy but he has a picture of an equilateral triangle that is broken up into three segments in the ration $\tau:1:\tau$ on every side and lots of lines joining these points. i won't be surprised if the golden ratio $\tau$ figures in this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I actually made such a big mistake in the base image. I'm recreating the image now.

Comment: @abel: Ok I updated the pictures and it seems that the circle is inscribed in the resulting pentagon. However this is optical and I would like to verify. I also included a calculation which takes this assumption and calculates x. However if my assumption isn't correct I think I first need to get the angle of rotation to make it a regular pentagon...

Comment: how did you go from the six interior circles to five?

Comment: @abel: where do you see five? The pentagon below represents the purple pentagon in the picture above. **Edit: the purple pentagon is (should be) appearing after rotation over the `green` x axis**.

Comment: how do you get the purple pentagon? i meant how did you go from the six circles to the five vertices of the pentagon?

Comment: Lol, just edited my comment.

Comment: @abel: Just to make sure, I made another mistake calculating $x$. I now used a calculator which gave: $1.453085$ This is still based on the fact that the pentagon exactly inscribes the original circle after the rotation around the `green` x axis. And it still leaves the angle of rotation unknown...

Comment: @abel the purple pentagon is what i'm after. It should result from a certain rotation of the dodecahedron on the green axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction does not yield the projection of a regular dodecahedron onto a plane. Take for instance the upmost pentagon in your figure: its horizontal side is parallel to the plane, so its length (which can be calculated to be 
$4\sqrt3/5$) should be the actual length of every edge of the dodecahedron. But if so the other sides of that pentagon should be shorter than the horizontal one, which is not the case. In addition, the length of a pentagon circumscribed to a unit radius circle is $2\sqrt{5-2\sqrt5}$, which is different from $4\sqrt3/5$.

In any case the rotation angle $\theta$ you need (for a real dodecahedron) is just $\angle AOB$, where $O$ is the dodecahedron centre, $A$ is the centre of the blue pentagon and $B$ is the vertex at the center of your diagram. Using the coordinates of the vertices which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#/media/File:Dodecahedron_vertices.png), one can compute (warning: a previous value was not correct):
$$
\cos\theta={1\over\sqrt{15+6\sqrt5}},
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad 
\theta\approx 79.188°.
$$

[image]

EDIT.

To better explain my above remarks, you can see below a diagram made with GeoGebra. The blue edge of the dodecahedron in space is parallel to the projection plane, hence its projection should have the same length (0.34641 in picture below, where the external hexagon has unit side). The green edge, on the other hand, is not parallel to the projection plane and the length of its projection should be less than its length in space. But in your construction the length of the supposed projection is 0.35277, which is greater. It follows that the construction doesn't reproduce faithfully a dodecahedron projection.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the projection is false. Isn't it equal to the orthogonal projection centered by vertex? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Dodecahedron_t0_A2.png.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I see what you mean (https://imgur.com/HRcyiz8). To be fair I did try to be clear about the dodecahedron being in 3D space not a orthogonal projection (aside from my doubt in the previous comment). I think the question still remains (or actually you answered it with `82.1666` i believe, need to validate ("visually") it still)!

Comment: The angle I computed is of course valid for any regular dodecahedron. My remark about the projection was there just to explain that your second question cannot be answered.

Comment: Warning: I checked the value of the angle with GeoGebra and found it was not correct. I then repeated the calculation and edited my answer to give the correct value. Sorry for the error.

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to calculate the value for the expression you wrote down (I seem to be getting: `0.247...`). However I do like the fact that the angle of `79.188` degrees is equal to the value of the `cosine` at that uuhm _point_?

Comment: I don't understand your remark about "uuhm" point (what is it?). To compute that angle I considered the coordinates given at that Wikipedia page, in particular vertex $B=(-1/\phi,0,\phi)$ and point $A={1\over5}(2+2\phi+1/\phi, 0,2+\phi)$ which is the center of the face right-up in the picture. As the dodecahedron is centered at $(0,0,0)$ you have then: $$\cos\theta={A\cdot B\over|A|\,|B|}.$$