# Analytic-geometrical properties of dodecahedron

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polyhedra, platonic-solids

Consider the following projection of a dodecahedron:

[image: Centered by vertex]

An equilateral triangle can be projected to make points $A, B, C, D, E, F$ intersect with it's edges. What would be the mathematical proof (if any) for saying:

> Lines $AB$, $CD$ and $EF$ exactly overlay/intersect with the edges of the triangle

[image: With Triangle]

> This is a more focused question in order to hopefully get some more traction on this question: [Mathematical properties of two dimensional projection of three dimensional rotated object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200986/mathematical-properties-of-two-dimensional-projection-of-three-dimensional-rotat)

Comment: if you have access to coxeters regular polytopes, please see the figure 6.2D on page 97.

Comment: I found some free sample pages and this seems to describe it. I can't properly read `fig 6.2d` due to the blur so it makes it difficult for me to comprehend. But please correct me if I'm wrong, i'm working with the *small stellated dodecahedron* here? $/frac{5}{2},5$  (can't get mathjax right)

Comment: Don't those three edges extend to form an equilateral triangle even before projection?